# SharpDXException on setting Shader inputLayout

Tags: c#, exception, directx, sharpdx

This didnt used to throw this exception but now it does

```
    if (shader.ShaderInput == null) shader.ShaderInput = new InputLayout(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(shader.CompilationResult), new[] { new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32_Float, 0, 0), new InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32_Float, 16, 0) });
```

The only useful information it gives me is

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll

Additional information: HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], Message: The parameter is incorrect.
```

Im not sure why this is doing this and im still pretty new to SharpDX

AssetsLoader.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;

    using SharpDX;
    using SharpDX.DXGI;
    using SharpDX.Direct3D;
    using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
    using SharpDX.D3DCompiler;

    using SharpDX.XAudio2;
    using SharpDX.Multimedia;

    using OneEngine.DataTypes;
    using OneEngine.Core;

    namespace OneEngine.Assets
    {
        public static class AssetsLoader
        {
            public static void LoadImage(Image image)
            {
                image.Texture = Texture2D.FromFile<Texture2D>(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, image.FilePath);
                image.ShaderResourceView = new ShaderResourceView(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, image.Texture);
                image.Sampler = new SamplerState(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, new SamplerStateDescription()
                    {
                        // TODO > Make Simplifier classes for these values and adapt to engine settings
                        Filter = Filter.MinMagMipLinear,
                        AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
                        AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
                        AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
                        BorderColor = Color.Black,
                        ComparisonFunction = Comparison.Never,
                        MaximumAnisotropy = 16,
                        MipLodBias = 0,
                        MinimumLod = 0,
                        MaximumLod = 16
                    });
                }

                public static void LoadShader(Shader shader)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < shader.ShaderTypes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        switch (shader.ShaderTypes[i])
                        {
                            case EShaderType.VERTEX:
                                shader.CompilationResult = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(shader.FilePath, "VS", "vs_5_0");
                                shader.VertexShader = new VertexShader(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, shader.CompilationResult);
                                break;
                            case EShaderType.PIXEL:
                                shader.CompilationResult = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(shader.FilePath, "PS", "ps_5_0");
                                shader.PixelShader = new PixelShader(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, shader.CompilationResult);
                                break;
                            case EShaderType.GEOMETRY:
                                shader.CompilationResult = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(shader.FilePath, "GS", "gs_5_0");
                                shader.GeometryShader = new GeometryShader(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, shader.CompilationResult);
                                break;
                            case EShaderType.COMPUTE:
                                shader.CompilationResult = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(shader.FilePath, "CS", "cs_5_0");
                                 shader.ComputeShader = new ComputeShader(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, shader.CompilationResult);
                                 break;
                            case EShaderType.DOMAIN:
                                shader.CompilationResult = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(shader.FilePath, "DS", "ds_5_0");
                                shader.DomainShader = new DomainShader(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, shader.CompilationResult);
                                break;
                            case EShaderType.HULL:
                                shader.CompilationResult = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(shader.FilePath, "HS", "hs_5_0");
                                shader.HullShader = new HullShader(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, shader.CompilationResult);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
        if (shader.ShaderInput == null) shader.ShaderInput = new InputLayout(OneEngineInstance.EngineInstance.Device, ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(shader.CompilationResult), new[] { new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32_Float, 0, 0), new InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32_Float, 16, 0) });
    }

    public static void LoadAudio(Audio audio)
    {
        audio.Stream = new SoundStream(File.OpenRead(audio.FilePath));
        audio.Format = audio.Stream.Format;
        audio.Buffer = new AudioBuffer
        {
            Stream = audio.Stream.ToDataStream(), AudioBytes = (int)audio.Stream.Length, Flags = BufferFlags.EndOfStream
        };
        audio.Stream.Close();
        audio.Voice = new SourceVoice(AudioCore.XAudio, audio.Format, true);
        if (audio.IsLoopable) audio.Buffer.LoopCount = audio.LoopTimes;
    }

    public static void LoadVideo()
    {

    }

    public static void LoadFont()
    {

    }

    public static void LoadLanguage()
    {

    }
}

public enum EShaderType
{
    VERTEX, PIXEL, GEOMETRY, COMPUTE, DOMAIN, HULL
}
```

}

Shader.cs

```
using System;

using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.D3DCompiler;

using OneEngine.Assets;

namespace OneEngine.DataTypes
{
public sealed class Shader
{
    private String filePath;
    private EShaderType[] shaderTypes;

    private CompilationResult shaderByteCode;

    private VertexShader vs;
    private PixelShader ps;
    private GeometryShader gs;
    private ComputeShader cs;
    private DomainShader ds;
    private HullShader hs;

    private InputLayout shaderInput;
    private InputElement[] inputElements;

    public Shader(String shaderFilePath, EShaderType[] types, InputElement[] elemets)
    {
        this.filePath = shaderFilePath;
        this.shaderTypes = types;
        this.inputElements = elemets;
    }

    public void RemoveFromMemory()
    {
        if (shaderByteCode != null) shaderByteCode.Dispose();
        if (vs != null) vs.Dispose();
        if (ps != null) ps.Dispose();
        if (gs != null) gs.Dispose();
        if (cs != null) cs.Dispose();
        if (ds != null) ds.Dispose();
        if (hs != null) hs.Dispose();
    }

    public String FilePath
    {
        get { return filePath; }
    }

    public EShaderType[] ShaderTypes
    {
        get { return shaderTypes; }
        set { shaderTypes = value; }
    }

    public CompilationResult CompilationResult
    {
        get { return shaderByteCode; }
        set { shaderByteCode = value; }
    }

    public VertexShader VertexShader
    {
        get { return vs; }
        set { vs = value; }
    }

    public PixelShader PixelShader
    {
        get { return ps; }
        set { ps = value; }
    }

    public GeometryShader GeometryShader
    {
        get { return gs; }
        set { gs = value; }
    }

    public ComputeShader ComputeShader
    {
        get { return cs; }
        set { cs = value; }
    }

    public DomainShader DomainShader
    {
        get { return ds; }
        set { ds = value; }
    }

    public HullShader HullShader
    {
        get { return hs; }
        set { hs = value; }
    }

    public InputLayout ShaderInput
    {
        set { shaderInput = value; }
        get { return shaderInput; }
    }

    public InputElement[] ShaderInputElements
    {
        get { return inputElements; }
    }
}
}
```

If you need anything else, the project is open source https://github.com/TheNanonNetwork/OneGames

Comment: can you post the shader code? the github link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your Graphics Device with DeviceCreationFlags.Debug and if the input layout is failing to create properly, then it'll tell you why.

Also, are you sure your Color attribute is supposed to be at an offset of 16 bytes given that the attribute before it is only 12 bytes in size?

Comment: Ill try that now and also yes the color is ok, i had to look at the sharpdx samples for that part and its works fine

Comment: Tried it and now im getting this HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], Message: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: I think i found out why, the shaderinput needs the bytecode from the vertex shader but what my system is doing is setting the value for each shader and then setting the shader input